# SQLITE basic syntax

Tags: c, sqlite

I seem to misunderstand a basic syntax, why this sample works:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "insert into test values('boo','boo',0);", strlen(querystring)+1 , &stmt, NULL);

if ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) != SQLITE_DONE)
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: sqlite3_step() %d. Error Message %s;\n",rc,sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

But when I try this query:
"insert into test(strtest) values('boo');"

I get an error:
Error: sqlite3_step() 19. Error Message constraint failed;

What am I missing?

table test is: "create table test (blobtest BLOB(4) NOT NULL, strtest VARCHAR NOT NULL,  inttest INTEGER NOT NULL );"

Thanks,
Doori Bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three columns are declared as `NOT NULL`, and they do not have a default value.

So your query:

```
insert into test(strtest) values('boo');
```

Is only assigning `blobtest` a value, leaving out `strtest` and `inttest` which cannot be null.

You can fix this by either adding two more values, or you can change the table schema to default to something, e.g.:

```
create table test (
    blobtest BLOB(4) NOT NULL,
    strtest VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    inttest INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

(or you could take out `NOT NULL` if you would like them to be `NULL`-able)

Comment: Thank you very much! (I suppose you actually meant that strtest being set to 'boo' but blobtest and inttest been left with no NULL or a default, right?

Comment: @Doori Bar - Nope, `blobtest` is the first column declared in your schema, so the first value in `values(...)` will be applied to that column, unless you specify explicit column ordering, e.g.: `insert into test (inttest, strtest, blobtest) values(...)`

Comment: But I did? "insert into test(strtest) values('boo');"